# What is the probability of getting a $9$ exactly once in $3$ throws with a pair of dice?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-distribution, dice

**Question :** What is the probability of getting a $9$ exactly once in $3$ throws with a pair of dice?

**My Try:** There are five possibilities: $(4,5), (5,4), (3,3), (6,3), (3,6)$.

Therefore, Probability is $\frac{5}{36}$ in a single throw.

Using Binomial Distribution
$$\binom{3}1 \cdot \bigg(\frac{5}{36}\bigg)^1 \cdot  \bigg(\frac{31}{36}\bigg)^2$$

Answer: $0.308$

The book's answer is $64/243 = 0.26$ which is slightly less so I wonder whether I have missed out on some detail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you think (3,3) adds up to 9?  You only have 4 out of 36 ways to get 9 with two dice.  That gives $3 \frac{1}{9} (\frac{8}{9})^2$

Comment: @karakfa got it. Thank you so much.